# three.js load .obj to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

just beginning out with javascript and three.js and have a quick query. I have loaded a simple .obj file like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

but I want a way to be able to modify the rotation of the object for later on. I tried this:

```
var geo;
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
            geo = object;
    scene.add( geo );
} );
```

So I can later on update the `geo.position.x` in the animation loop. The code loads the object but when I try to update the position I get a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
```

How is it that the variable is undefined as a declared it in the parent scope of the animate function?

Probably a simple answer but I'm stumped!

#### Edit

Im using the OBJLoader.js from this link

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js

Comment: Loading is asynchronous. In the animation loop, try `if ( geo ) geo.position.x += delta;`

Answer (score -1):

Try make it a window.variable

```
window.geo;
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'test.obj', function ( object ) {
            window.geo = object;
    scene.add( window.geo );
} );
```

Comment: No this wont work either. The loaders work in asynchronous mode so the data is not there when you expect it. At least not with this implementation.